# Получить текст ссылок при парсинге страницы

Tags: node.js, синтаксический-анализ, javascript

Не пойму как спарсить названия ссылок (марки автомобилей)
Необходимо получить массив названий марок авто со страницы, но с регулярками что то туго совсем у меня. Может кто то поможет.

cars.auto.ru

Пишу парсер

```
var request     = require('request')
    , async     = require('async')
    , HttpError = require('../../error').HttpError;

exports.get = function(req, res, next) {

    async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            request(URL, function (err, response, body) {
                if(err) return callback(err);
                // body - весь код страницы
                    callback(null, body));
                }
            });
        }
    ],
    function(err, data) {
        if(err) return next(new HttpError(403, err));

        res.end(data);
    });
};
```

Нужна регулярка которая возьмет текст ссылок

```
<div class="cell-.*?"><a href="/cars/used/.*?">(.*?)</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну уж на ноде точно не надо делать регулярками, [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jsdom)

> A JavaScript implementation of the DOM and HTML standards

Comment: просто супер! Спасибо большое!